# How to use Hivecontext inside map transformation

Tags: apache-spark

I have an use case wherein i create a dataframe from a hive table. The design is such that for every row of the hive table, i need to contact another hive table for retrieving some more pieces of information.

```
val flowDf = hiveContext.sql("select * from humsdb.t_flow_sample")   

var x = flowDf.map { row =>
    var configuration = hiveContext.sql("query")
   configuration.collect.foreach{println}
   ...
   ...
 }
```

I got a nullpointerexception when i tried to use hivecontext inside the map process. I went through few posts in stackoverflow and understood that it is not possible to use hivecontext inside the map process. Hence, would like to understand any other workaround to get access to the hivecontext inside the map.

Comment: Please post more on what are you trying to achieve, what approaches have you tried with code snippets. I'd suggest you to join the two data frames instead of firing hive query for each row.

Comment: @Bala, hope you being long time user in SO will be knowing how to ask question. I have skipped flagging. Please edit your post with your code.

Comment: Edited now . thanks for not flagging

Comment: it seems that you should join these dataframes